# UFT 14.0 is not able to recognize objects in chrome version 60

Tags: hp-uft

UFT 14.0 is not able to recognize objects in chrome version 60 .

I have the HP UFT functional testing agent enabled in the extensions.

Comment: I'm not seeing a problem with UFT with Chrome 60, did it work before Chrome upgraded?

Answer (score -1):

Have you attempted to adjust the display size in the windows machine to 100% and adjust the resolution to 1280x1024? I was having a similar problem and this fixed it.